# Laravel Validation : how to set 'required_if' and 'integer'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two field
qty, status
I want to set a rule 
qty must 'integer'
qty required when status is 0.
qty can be empty when status is 1
I try to set rules as below

```php
[
    'qty'    => 'integer|required_if:status,0',
    'status' => 'required|integer|between:0,1'
]
```

But I don't know why when status is 1,
do not show required error, but show integer error.

Comment: Try to add `nullable` validate to `qty`

Comment: thank a lot,[
    'qty'    => 'integer|nullable|required_if:status,0',
    'status' => 'required|integer|between:0,1'
]

Answer (score 0):

You have used integer between 0 and 1 that never occured so change rules like this:

```
[
    'qty' => 'integer|required_if:status,0',
    'status' => 'required|integer|in:0,1'
]
```

Another thing is when status is 0 you need qty so validation will pass when status is 1 and no qty is provided.

I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
[
'qty' => 'required_if:status,==,0',
'status' => 'required|integer|between:0,1',
]
```